# ASP.NET Core 2.0 Adding authentication

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

So when I made an ASP.NET Core 2.0 web application a while ago there was no need for authentication so I clicked the 'No Authentication' box when first creating the project. Now some time later I do want to add authentication.

So what I did was read [the documentation on Identity](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/identity?tabs=visual-studio%2Caspnetcore2x) on the Windows website and follow that guide.

I added the lines to my Startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    //Add dbContext

    //Add some services

    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
        .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyOwnDbContext>()
        .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

    services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
    {
        // Password settings
        options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
        options.Password.RequiredLength = 8;
        options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
        options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
        options.Password.RequireLowercase = false;
        options.Password.RequiredUniqueChars = 6;

        // Lockout settings
        options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
        options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 10;
        options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;

        // User settings
        options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    });

    services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options =>
    {
        // Cookie settings
        options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
        options.Cookie.Expiration = TimeSpan.FromDays(150);
        options.LoginPath = "/Account/Login"; // If the LoginPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Login
        options.LogoutPath = "/Account/Logout"; // If the LogoutPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/Logout
        options.AccessDeniedPath = "/Account/AccessDenied"; // If the AccessDeniedPath is not set here, ASP.NET Core will default to /Account/AccessDenied
        options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    });

    services.AddMvc();
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseAuthentication();
}
```

And I added the AccountController, the necessary viewmodels and the views.
Now when I fill in the Register form I should (according to Microsoft's documentation) get this error:

[image: apply-migrations]

However I get this error:
[image: Actual error]

How do I get into the situation where ASP.Net Core 2.0 wants to scaffold a migration so I can just create a database (or a table) for my authentication?
Or are there different approaches to this problem that can get the authentication working?

**Edit**
I changed MyOwnDbContext to inherit from

```
IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
```

instead of DbContext but I'm still having the same error.

Comment: Tried the same with : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser,                            ApplicationRole, string> with no result

Comment: Please show your actual database context class. Make sure, you are calling the base `OnModelCreating` method properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is this line:

```
.AddEntityFrameworkStores<DbContext>()
```

You should not use the Entity Framework `DbContext` class, you should use your own class that implements `DbContext` and has your tables and configuration. Given that you want to use the classes that Identity provides for EFCore, you should do something along the lines of:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;

public class MyContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyContext(DbContextOptions<MyContext> options) : base(options) { }
}
```

With this, change your startup to:

```
services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
   options.UseSqlServer("connectionstring"));

services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>()
```

Comment: I edited my question to match my actual code better. I'm using my own implementation of a class that inherits from DbContext as usual.

Comment: @Jeroen your question still does not reflect my answer

Comment: MyOwnDbContext class only contains DbSets I use for non-authentication purposes

Comment: Is it correct that the ApplicationDbContext class is different from the MyContext class?

Comment: @Jeroen Not sure what you mean, it's just a name. I never use the default `ApplicationDbContext` name. You must, however, implement the `IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>` interface

Answer (score 1):

Your context class needs to extend AplicationUser

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, 
                                    ApplicationRole, string>
{
    //The context class constructor
    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
    //the models that you are using
    public DbSet<ModelExampleClass> ModelExampleClasses { get; set; }
}
```

Don't forget to include:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
```

Or you can start a new project and check the authentication box (It is better)

Comment: I tried this solution but it didn't work unfortunately. I'm still getting the same error. Just to be clear: ApplicationUser and ApplicationRole are classes you made yourself right? which inherit from IdentityUser for user and IdentityRole for role

Comment: With 'your solution' I mean making my dbContext inherit from IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, 
                                    ApplicationRole, string>

Comment: Making a new project works just fine but that's not what I want. As my current project is already quite big.

Comment: By default it adds ApplicationUser. I have added the ApplicationRole that is indeed created by myself and the string value

Comment: You can create a new project anyway just to check the context and the startup files default configs. I think that it could help you checking if you miss something in your configuration

Comment: I've created a new project with 'Individual User Accounts' authentication turned on and compared the Startup.cs and the database contexts. They are the same.

Comment: that is strange. Maybe you are missing a "using"

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had two distinct ApplicationUser classes in my solution that I was confusing with eachother. When I found out about this I deleted one of the two and consistently used the remaining class. My database context now looks like this:

```
public class MyOwnDatabaseContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{
    public MyOwnDatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<MyOwnDatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(builder);
        // Customize the ASP.NET Identity model and override the defaults if needed.
        // For example, you can rename the ASP.NET Identity table names and more.
        // Add your customizations after calling base.OnModelCreating(builder);
    }
}
```

And the ApplicationUser class looks like this

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
}
```

In which the IdentityUser is from the 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity' namespace

Comment: This answer, while it is the correct answer for your problem, makes your question off-topic as we couldn't have guessed that

Comment: Should I remove the question to avoid wasting people's time?

Comment: If you edited your question to include the relevant part, it'd make the 2 answers useless, so yeah

Comment: I can't delete the question because of the rules of StackOverflow regarding deletion of questions: https://stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-questions